# Exim - Limit sent mail bounce to the user

Tags: exim, mta

Exist some way of to limit sent mail bounce to the user with system filter of Exim MTA?
I need set the header from of the mail bounces in a file, but not know like read it content.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a central filter to filter those bounced messages. With the current exim.pl you can track who is sending emails. There is an option to turn on a limit for how many emails are sent by a particular user. To enable this limit, simply add the number of emails you'd like to allow per day to the /etc/virtual/limit file.

```
echo 300 > /etc/virtual/limit_username
```

where username is the user for who you would like to give the limit to.

Also Refer: http://www.farhad.ca/2006/07/27/how-to-disable-delayed-bounce-back-messages-in-exim/